# UISplitViewController on iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: swift, interface, uisplitviewcontroller, iphone-6-plus

I make an application on iPhone and iPad. I have the `UISplitViewController` and I use it on iPad. When I launch my application on iPhone 6 Plus (simulator) `UISplitViewController` doesn't work. (It's good work on iPad 3 or iPad Air 2 and iPhone 5s). I make following into my code.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    if (UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetailParse", sender: nil)
    } else if (UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("showParse", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

My screen from iPad works well
[image]

My screen from iPhone 6 Plus (simulator)
[image]

**UPDATE**:
I updated my code which defines on which device it works and it did work! Into the code I define the height of a current device and if bigger than 2000 pixels I use segue for iPad. But I don't like this solution. Are there any ideas?

My updated code is below.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    var screen = UIScreen.mainScreen().currentMode?.size.height
    if (UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad) || screen >= 2000 && UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape == true {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetailParse", sender: nil)
    } else if (UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("showParse", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see on the screen you've provided - you have embedded `UITabBarController` in your MasterViewController. I have done this previously as well and the trick is to not forget where you're **pushing** - not in the `UINavigationController` because that's not the Master, the Master is the `UITabBarController`.

I did this:

```
self.tabBarController?.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: nil)
```

Which worked for me well for this Storyboard layout:

[image]